Wigner rotation and conservation laws
The context:

In a frame K, there's an extended object with mass.
Initially the object is stationary, with no spin.
The object then moves in a circular orbit at constant speed.
No torque is applied to the object.
The object's orientation begins to precess (because of Wigner rotation)

The question:
In the world of Newton, it takes work to change the spin of an object.
For the case described above, special relativity asserts that no work is being done on the object to change its spin (from zero to non-zero). That is, special relativity asserts that Wigner rotation is a purely kinematic effect.
How is Wigner rotation compatible with conservation of energy, and conservation of angular momentum?

You need to be a lot more concrete with the specific way the object is acceelerated up to start moving, and continuously accelerated to have the circular motion, and then the slowing down. The result you are looking for might well cancel out in the details. As your question now stands, it might well not be solvable.

I have amended the question in response to your comment.

"The object then moves in a circular orbit at constant speed" means that you are not in an inertial frame, and conservation of momentum does not apply.

The Wigner rotation (also known as Thomas precession) is due to the object's direction being a vector perpendicular to the object's 4-velocity. The tip of the 4-velocity vector is constrained to move on the surface of the hyperboloid $-v_0^2+ v_1^2+v_3^2+v_4^2=-1$ embedded in a Minkowski signature velocity space. This is a negative curvature manifold with the object's direction lying in its tangent space. The Wigner rotation is simply parallel transport on the negative curvature space. In other words, the  object appears to rotate in space precisely because it is not rotating (i.e is parallel transported) in space-time.

I have looked into the details of the geometry of the unit hyperboloid related to 4-velocity. It's very interesting! Here's a link to some code that I wrote to explore it.
